# Dynamic text for SO10 texts in SapScript

Tags: sapscript

Im trying to change some texts in SO10. I´d like to check a variable and (depending on the result) would like to use different lines of the text.
Is it possible to use:

/: IF &variable& is initial.

** Text1

/: ELSE.

** Text2

/: ENDIF.

in SO10-texts?
The Variable contains the users mobile number but isn´t filled for all users.

Comment: This should answer your question: [Reference documentation for IF in SAPscript](https://help.sap.com/viewer/59204ae5e0d745628df068a6ec7591b0/7.5.5/en-US/4e3407f763de02c2e10000000a15822b.html)

Comment: Thanks. That helped for another problem i tried to solve, but im unable to check the value of my variable, if it isn´t filled. Thats what i was trying to do with the "is initial" statement. I´ve tried IF &VARIABLE& GT '0'. but the line of text was still printed.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by "escaping" the part of text i wanted to hide. By setting '& text 'VARIABLE& the part of the text is only displayed, if the variable is filled. I found this in another text a former colleague created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by "escaping" the part of text i wanted to hide. By setting '& text 'VARIABLE& the part of the text is only displayed, if the variable is filled.